# Microsoft Access checking account DB with Categories, Subcategories, and dependent fields

Tags: ms-access

I understand - and have created - a self-referencing table that contains Categories & Subcategories.  SO, you get a table that [looks like this](http://sqllessons.com/categories.html):

```
Categories Table:
id, primary Key autoNumber
category, text
parentID, foreign Key, number

categories.ID has a one-to-many relationship with categories.parentID
```

**==Here is what I'm having a really tough time understanding==**

I also have a Transactions table used to track a purchase, and two columns to record the Category and its Subcategory.  Think "Automobile:  Gasoline", or "Healthcare:  Prescriptions".

```
Transactions Table:
id, primaryKey, autoNumber
payee, shortText
Category, foreign key, (number, comboBox)
Subcategory (number, comboBox)

categories.ID has a one-to-many relationship with Transactions.Category
```

I can't find the appropriate way to populate Category and Subcategory in the Transactions table.

So far, I was able to pull all distinct categories from the Categories Table with a SQL statement similar to the example below.  *(Any Category with a NULL parentID is considered a root category).*

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories
WHERE (((Categories.[parentID]) Is Null))
ORDER BY Categories.category DESC;
```

My problem is finding a way to get Transactions.Subcategory to list only the subcategories associated with the chosen root category.

I don't know how to do this in Access.

Any tips, advice, etc., would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can a subcategory has subcategories aswell? If so you could then get a tree of categories, making it slightly more difficult to give an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649764/how-to-find-root-nodes

Comment: I don't need anything beyond the first child.  Also:  I'm not married to the self-referencing table.